# Silverlight Simple and Complex Properties

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I was asked recently in an interview to give an example of a simple property and a complex property in Silverlight.  I think they were asking about dependency properties and attached properties but I'm not sure.  I've never heard the term Silverlight Simple Property or Silverlight Complex Property and googling hasn't helped.  Are these common terms that I've just missed up until now?  If so, what do they refer to?

Comment: It's not a term I've come across either.

Comment: I've never heard of them either and have been working with Silverlight for nearly 3 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your interviewer wasn't using the most common terminology for whatever concept they were trying to describe.

Or...

They may have been testing you to see if you'd press back for more "requirements". You should have pressed them for more information so you could have worked out what they meant and answered their question.

Answer (score 1):

maybe simple properties are of type string, int, bool, etc. where complex properties are custom classes (or struct) like Company { string companyName; }

Answer (score 1):

Haven't heard anything like that before either but...

...maybe they were referring to lazy setting for simple:

```
SimpleProperty { get; set; }
```

and complex to customizing the setter:

```
ComplexProperty
{
   get
   {
      return _complexProperty
   }
   set
   {
      //Do some "complex" stuff here like maybe computing how many steps to the moon then add it to the current value before setting to the field :))
      _complexProperty = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("ComplexProperty");
   }
}
```

Comment: What's lazy setting? Do you mean Auto Property vs explicit backing field?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess.
Take ListBox as Ex. x:Name is a simple property, while ItemsPanel is Complex property(which cannot assigned a value inline)

Answer (score 0):

A simple property would be something like FontSize which you could set easily with a string using property-attribute syntax.

Ex.

```
<Label FontSize="10">My Label</Label>
```

A complex property would be one requiring a object that may in itself contain a number of properties, such as a gradient brush.  You would typically set this using property-element syntax.

Ex.

```
<Button>
   <Button.Background>
      <LinearGradientBrush>
         <GradientStop Offset="0.00" Color="Yellow" />
         <GradientStop Offset="0.50" Color="Green" />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
   </Button.Background>
</Button>
```